# Deleting Specific Cells Excel

Tags: vba, excel, del

What I'm trying to do is have the program go through is find a certain value from within a column of cells and see if it matches with one cell after I special paste the value, and if there is a match delete the associated cell and its row of cells. What is happening is that the special pasting part of the program is working, but the associated cells are not being deleted. To clarify, I'm trying to delete a whole row from a certain column based on whether there's a match

```
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Dim Aud_Tot As Integer
Aud_Tot = Application.InputBox("How big is your audit", , , , , , , 1)
Do While True
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Not IsError(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Copy
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For j = 2 To Aud_Tot
            If Cells(j, 24).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                Range(Cells(j, 24), (Cells(j, 42))).ClearContents
            End If
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: *deleting the associated cells is not* - what do you expect to have that is not happening? hard to help you when it's not clear what your current result versus expectation is. For example, do you want to delete the entire row? Or do you just want to clear the contents of the cells from column 24 to column 42 for each row in j?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to delete the row but you are only using `ClearContents`.  To delete you can change that line to `Range(Cells(j, 24), (Cells(j, 42))).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp`, you can also use `xlShiftToLeft`.

Did you want to delete the *entire* row or just the range you have?

Comment: I just want to delete the specific range, I believe the delete in general is not working because of how I exit out of the While loop

Comment: Then the above will work, you'll just have to decide which way you want to shift after deleting it.